# Docker Node and MongoDB. MongoDB Compass not show data but in terminal show the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, apple-m1, mongodb-compass

In my app, after register user. Data store in my local db. Im want monitor using mongodb compass but data not appeared in my compass.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  adam:
    image: adam
    container_name: adam
    build:
      context: ../backend/adam
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../backend/adam:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null 

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
  adam:
    driver: local
```

[My terminal show the data but not appeared in MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebLLu.png)

Im already try changed the url, but still not working.

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

```
mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017
```